# Mysql error duplicate results

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a mysql query and got same result twice. Now i can't fix the problem. can anyone please help me.

```
SELECT first_name , second_name
FROM profile_doctors_main , category
WHERE (first_name LIKE "%'.(string)$name.'%" OR second_name LIKE "%'.$name.'%")
    AND category_name LIKE "%'.$category.'%" AND city LIKE "%'.$city.'%"
```

result = 
Sharon Zing

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: `GROUP BY (first_name , second_name)` in the end of query or `SELECT DISTINCT first_name , second_name`

Comment: but in database there is only 2 tupples.how it's get?

Comment: Its getting from both tables , you haven't joined the tables

Comment: OK. I got solved that. i need to add join constraint. I have omited that. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you need to query data from multi tables, you should you use phrase 'JOIN', and alias the table when necessary.

and when you use **"JOIN"**, you should add the **"ON" condition**, which do something like "where" as  a filter that remove the duplicate results.

Try the sql following(as I do not know about the table field, it's just a sample)

```
'SELECT first_name , second_name FROM profile_doctors_main , category 
 on profile_doctors_main.xxx = category.xxx 
 WHERE (profile_doctors_main.first_name LIKE "%'.(string)$name.'%" 
 OR profile_doctors_main.second_name LIKE "%'.$name.'%") 
 AND category.category_name LIKE "%'.$category.'%" 
 AND profile_doctors_main.city LIKE "%'.$city.'%"'
```

there's another problem, that wrong match of the  "and" condition and the "or" condition .

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
 profile_doctors_main.first_name sfname,
  profile_doctors_main.second_name slname,
  category.first_name fname,
  category.second_name lname 
FROM
    profile_doctors_main,
    category 
  WHERE (
      profile_doctors_main.first_name LIKE "%'.(string)$name.'%" AND category.first_name LIKE "%'.(string)$name.'%"
      OR profile_doctors_main.second_name LIKE "%'.$name.'%" AND category.second_name LIKE "%'.$name.'%"
    ) 
    AND category_name LIKE "%'.$category.'%" 
    AND city LIKE "%'.$city.'%"
```